# Error when I add msw init code in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, msw

I got this message when I init msw for mock api.

```
node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:153
  while (match = re.exec(fileData)) lastMatch = match;
                    ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at retrieveSourceMapURL (L:\projects\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:153:21)
    at Array.<anonymous> (L:\projects\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:165:26)
    at L:\projects\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:64:24
    at mapSourcePosition (L:\projects\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:195:21)
    at wrapCallSite (L:\projects\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:387:20)
    at Function.prepareStackTrace (L:\projects\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:461:39)
    at maybeOverridePrepareStackTrace (node:internal/errors:141:29)
    at prepareStackTrace (node:internal/errors:115:5)
    at getCallFrame (L:\projects\node_modules\msw\src\utils\internal\getCallFrame.ts:12:23)
```

I wrote this code

```
import { rest } from "msw";

export const handlers = [
rest.get('http://localhost:3000/user', async (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
            message: "Welcome to"
        })
    )
}),
]
```

I think it's because of the Next.js webpack setting, but I don't know how to look at it.

This is my Next.js config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  i18n,
  env: {
    SERVER_API_URL: serverApiUrl,
    PORT: port,
    PROXY_HOST: process.env.PROXY_HOST || `http://localhost:${port}`,
    ENV: process.env.ENV || '-',
    SITE_ID: siteId,
  },
  webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
    const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    const newConfig = {
      ...config,
      mode: prod ? 'production' : 'development',
    }
    if (prod) {
      newConfig.devtool = 'hidden-source-map'
    }
    return newConfig
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/server/:path*',
        destination: `${serverApiUrl}/:path*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}
module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, nextConfig)
```